# Strongloop: ACLs not Working

Tags: acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm fairly new to the Strongloop API. To sum up my problem: 
I've connected a Mysql database to my Application. I already can do the Register(POST) of an extended User, but I am getting:

"statusCode": 401,
    "code": "LOGIN_FAILED",

.... on the LogIn(POST). Exploring other methods like findById and according to my ACL definition of my Extended User, I've found that the ACL definition can not be working, for the findByID isn't working either. Here follows the my extended user .json:

```
{
  "name": "UsersOficina",
  "plural": "UsersOficinas",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strict": true,
    "mysql": {
      "schema": "bo_oficina",
      "table": "usersOficina"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "fullName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "entidades_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "inheritAcls": false,
  "acls": [
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principal": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "create"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "deleteById"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "login"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "logout"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "findById"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "updateAttributes"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "confirm"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "resetPassword",
    "accessType": "EXECUTE"
  }
],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT[1]

The error when DEBUG:loopback:user is used, is "Invalid Password". It's misleading. The password is simply the digit 2 ("password":"2").